# Fast access of a subset of rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, optimization

I need to access the number of rows in a DataFrame associated with several combinations of column values.

This is the gist of what I'm doing:

```
for col1, col2, col3 in column_values:
    n = df.loc[(df.col1 == col1) & (df.col2 == col2) & (df.col3 == col3)].shape[0]
    print n
```

I'm finding that this is *very slow* when `column_values` is a long list.  The speed is the same whether I use `df.loc[]`, `df[]`, or `df.ix[]`.

Is there a faster way to access row counts?

Comment: Not sure of what you wanna do, but I'd say that the bottleneck is not df.loc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column_values is a list of tuples, I'd recommend counting only once:

```
grouped = df.groupby([col1, col2, col3]).count()
grouped.reindex(columns_values, fill_value=0)
```